# Ionic - events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Whenever I modify my code on VS Code I have to run **ionic serve** or **ionic lab** to view the result of my changes!! Before, I was used to only save the project and see the result just in time But now I have this error when I save my project :

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

So now I’m obliged to run ionic lab and wait for any single change (waste of time as you know).

Any solution please? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like an issue with the last update of Google Chrome.

I fixed it manually with `npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact`